# Find the given inverse Laplace transform.

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

This problem has really got me stumped, and I thought that I had it solved, but I am guessing I had messed up somewhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

Given:

$$\mathrm{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{16s}{16s^2+1}\right)$$

The answer I initially got was $\cos\left(\frac{t}{16}\right)$, but that is incorrect.

Comment: Can you see how item 8 can be applied ($a = \dfrac{1}{4}$): http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf? Your answer is not far off $$\cos\left(\dfrac{t}{4}\right)$$ Now, do it using the definition (integral) approach.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thank you very much.